# Jech's exercise 12.1 (1st Edition)

Tags: logic, set-theory

The exercise is:

> Let $\varphi\newcommand{\dom}{\operatorname{dom}}$ be a formula. There is a Gödel operation $G$ such that for every transitive $U$ and all $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n} \in U$ $$ \{u \in U : U \models \varphi (u,x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n})\}= G(U,x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) $$
>   [Hint: use the normal form theorem]

I tryed to solve this exercise but I don't know how to write a formal solution.

We call $X_{i}= \{x_{i}\}\forall i=1,...,n$. So by the normal form theorem there is a Gödel operation $G$ such that $G(U,X_{1}, \dotsc , X_{n})=\{(u,x_{1},\dotsc,x_{n}) : u \in U\wedge\varphi(u, x_{1}, \dotsc , x_{n}) \}$. The set that we are looking for is $$\underbrace{\dom \dotso\dom}_{\text{$n$ times}} (G(U,X_{1}, \dotsc , X_{n})).$$  We used both $\{x,y\}$ and $\dom(X)$ that are Gödel operations.

My problem is that the set that I built should be $\{u \in U : \varphi (u,x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n})\}$ which is a little bit different from $\{u \in U : U \models \varphi (u,x_{1}, \dotsc, x_{n})\}$. That is because the formula from which we start is not a restricted formula so, theoretically, we can't use the normal form theorem.

So how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It's always a good idea to write a general outline of what you tried to do to solve the exercise, it helps others give a good answer.

Comment: When you say you don’t know how to write a *formal* solution it suggests you at least have some intuition toward a solution. Tell us what you’re thinking and what gaps you need to fill to fully solve the problem. This will also give a sense of what facts you have access to for those of us who don’t have 1st edition Jech in front of us (in particular, what statement of the normal form theorem you are working with).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the original formula, use its relativization to $U$. In addition to giving you what you want at the end, since $U$ is a set, the relativization is $\Delta_0,$ which is required for the normal form theorem.